# Dominion Seaside cards. Wharf and Outpost in the same hand

Tags: dominion-seaside

I was playing in a two player game recently in which both Wharf and Outpost were being used. My opponent played both these cards in one turn. We decided that the extra turn dictated by Outpost, did not count as "the start of your next turn" dictated by Wharf. As a result he played Outpost with three cards and one buy, rather than 5 cards and two buys.

My question is did we do this right? Should the extra 2 cards and 1 buy from Wharf go the the extra turn from the Outpost, or should the duration phase of Wharf follow my turn that follows his bonus Outpost play?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your opponent should have drawn the extra cards on the next turn (the bonus one awarded by Outpost).

From the [Seaside rules](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=441&ei=MHzGUe6xJYO09gTF34CQCg&usg=AFQjCNEordsHW05uvGu_BIgrLQQw0N6ghw&sig2=qQYAqVliyHaV4U_N5Mw_Ag&bvm=bv.48293060,d.eWU), about Outpost:

> If you play Outpost as well as a "Now and at the start of your next turn" card, such as Merchant Ship, the turn from Outpost will be that next turn, so you'll get those coins then.

I think you can replace Merchant Ship with Wharf and get the same result.